# NSAutoreleasePool leak in Instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool, xcode-instruments

I do apologize if this have been asked before but i have not found a good answer.

When i run the Instruments i get a leak on this line in the code, not in main:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

I have been looking around and read somewhere that it may be a bug. Could someone please help me and share some light on this?

I did notice that i have the same name, "pool", in main also.

Comment: are you draining the pool? Like calling "[pool drain];" when you are done with your immense loop or background thread?

Answer (score 0):

The name doesn't matter;  there may be hundreds of variables named `pool` throughout the codebase.   What matters is scope.

Typically, you'll see this:

```
- someMethod
{
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     ... do stuff ...
     id something = [anObject retain];
     [pool drain];
     return [something autorelease];
 }
```

I.e. is your pool being drained?

(`drain` exists on iOS;  see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  However, in all cases, it is better to use `@autoreleasepool{ ... }`;  it works in ARC and MRR.)

Comment: IIRC, `drain` is Mac-only; it'd be `release` in iOS.

Comment: drain is a cool name :( lets add a category to add that method :D

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, my first problem on the first day learning how to code!

All I did was remove outright the entire line starting with:

> NSAutoreleasepool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasepool alloc] init];

replace it with:

> @autoreleasepool {

Then I deleted at the bottom of my program:

> [pool release];

Then closed off with the squiggly brackets.

I don't know why it works, my first day remember but it runs my program from the example book fine.